# google cloud sdk install error

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am getting the following error while installing google cloud SDK,

```
Output folder: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK
Downloading Google Cloud SDK core.
Extracting Google Cloud SDK core.
Create Google Cloud SDK bat file: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\cloud_env.bat
Installing components.
Welcome to the Google Cloud SDK!
This will install all the core command line tools necessary for working with
the Google Cloud Platform.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\\bin\bootstrapping\install.py", line 218, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\\bin\bootstrapping\install.py", line 196, in main
    Install(pargs.override_components, pargs.additional_components)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\\bin\bootstrapping\install.py", line 137, in Install
    InstallOrUpdateComponents(to_install, update=update)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\\bin\bootstrapping\install.py", line 180, in InstallOrUpdateComponents
    ['--quiet', 'components', verb, '--allow-no-backup'] + component_ids)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\cli.py", line 870, in Execute
    self._HandleAllErrors(exc, command_path_string, specified_arg_names)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\cli.py", line 908, in _HandleAllErrors
    exceptions.HandleError(exc, command_path_string, self.__known_error_handler)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\exceptions.py", line 526, in HandleError
    core_exceptions.reraise(exc)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\exceptions.py", line 137, in reraise
    six.reraise(type(exc_value), exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\cli.py", line 844, in Execute
    resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\backend.py", line 756, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\surface\components\update.py", line 109, in Run
    version=args.version)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\updater\update_manager.py", line 890, in Update
    command_path='components.update')
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\updater\update_manager.py", line 600, in _GetStateAndDiff
    command_path=command_path)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\updater\update_manager.py", line 583, in _GetLatestSnapshot
    *effective_url.split(','), command_path=command_path)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\updater\snapshots.py", line 178, in FromURLs
    for url in urls]
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\updater\snapshots.py", line 199, in _DictFromURL
    response = installers.ComponentInstaller.MakeRequest(url, command_path)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\updater\installers.py", line 293, in MakeRequest
    return ComponentInstaller._RawRequest(req, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\updater\installers.py", line 337, in _RawRequest
    should_retry_if=RetryIf, sleep_ms=500)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\util\retry.py", line 180, in RetryOnException
    exceptions.reraise(exc_info[1], tb=exc_info[2])
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\exceptions.py", line 137, in reraise
    six.reraise(type(exc_value), exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\util\retry.py", line 161, in TryFunc
    return func(*args, **kwargs), None
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\url_opener.py", line 78, in urlopen
    return opener.open(req, data, timeout)
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\temp\tmpi8qcvm\python\lib\urllib2.py", line 429, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\temp\tmpi8qcvm\python\lib\urllib2.py", line 447, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\temp\tmpi8qcvm\python\lib\urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\url_opener.py", line 63, in https_open
    return self.do_open(build, req)
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\temp\tmpi8qcvm\python\lib\urllib2.py", line 1195, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.get_selector(), req.data, headers)
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\temp\tmpi8qcvm\python\lib\httplib.py", line 1042, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\temp\tmpi8qcvm\python\lib\httplib.py", line 1082, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\temp\tmpi8qcvm\python\lib\httplib.py", line 1038, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\temp\tmpi8qcvm\python\lib\httplib.py", line 882, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\temp\tmpi8qcvm\python\lib\httplib.py", line 844, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\third_party\httplib2\python2\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1120, in connect
    raise SSLHandshakeError(e)
httplib2.python2.httplib2.SSLHandshakeError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661)
Failed to install.
```

Any idea?

Comment: Are you behind a corporate proxy? If yes this is a [known issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35907626) and you can find a workaround in the [comment 8](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35907626#comment8).

Comment: I could resolve this by disabling my antivirus setting

Comment: I'm getting the same error. What antivirus setting was it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could resolve this by disabling my antivirus setting

Comment: This post does not provide a solution because it contains no details on the solution. Which setting did you disable?